# How do I get the Closure Compiler to stop complaining about union types when calling a function?

Tags: javascript, javadoc, google-closure, google-closure-compiler

I'm seeing this in particular when using the jQuery-1.4.3 externs file.  The javadocs for that reads

```
/**
 * @param {(string|number|function(number,number))=} arg1
 * @return {(number|jQueryObject)}
 * @nosideeffects
 */
jQueryObject.prototype.width = function(arg1) {};
```

I have a call that looks like this:

```
   var w =  $(window).width();
    $('#whatever').width(w)
```

Closure complains:
WARNING - actual parameter 1 of jQueryObject.prototype.height does not match formal parameter
found   : (jQueryObject|null|number)
required: (function (number, number): ?|number|string|undefined)
        $('#Xobni').height($(window).height());

From playing around (removing the possible return types), I can see that the problem is that the first call to width can return possibly a jQueryObject, and since that's not a valid input, Closure gives me an error.  I tried adding this:

```
/**
 * @type {number}
 */
var w =  $(window).width();
$('#Xobni').width(w);
```

But then Closure complains:
WARNING - initializing variable
found   : (jQueryObject|null|number)
required: number
        var w =  $(window).width();

The problem is that when width takes an argument, it returns a jQueryObject.  When it doesn't take an argument, it returns a number.  So I know my call is okay, but the javadocs don't quite reflect that, and so Closure is warning me.  Is there a way to fix up the javadocs appropriately or a way to tell Closure I know this result will be a number.  I know I can probably suppress the error, but I'd like to know how to annotate these things better.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can override this as follows:

```
var w = /** @type {number} */ ($(window).width());
$('#whatever').width(w)
```

Comment: That worked perfectly.  Thanks!  It even works inline, if I use:
$('#whatever').width(/** @type {number} */ $(window).width());

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var w =  $(window).width();
w = parseInt(w.toString());
$('#whatever').width(w);
```

or this:

```
var w =  $(window).width() + '';
$('#whatever').width(w);
```

Comment: Thanks!  That's actually what I did to get past this issue, but nullptr's post provides a nice fix that doesn't involve any runtime mechanism.